# Intel HD Graphics 4000 only displaying native monitor resolution in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-10, drivers, resolution, integrated-graphics, intel-core-i5

Recently my graphics card died so I switched over to the integrated graphics on my motherboard. I plugged my DisplayPort cable into the motherboard, everything looked fine, and then after a few minutes, I heard the device connected chime, and my resolution was reduced to 1920x1080. When I checked Display Settings, that was the maximum resolution I could select. My monitor's native resolution is 3440x1440. It does however detect that the refresh rate is 120 hz.

One of my troubleshooting steps was to boot into Safe Mode and use Display Driver Uninstaller to wipe all the graphics drivers (from both nVidia and Intel) from my computer. At this point I realized that it automatically went to full native resolution in safe mode. So I assume the problem lies with the Intel driver.

So far I have tried changing to an HDMI cable, installing the latest drivers, an older driver, and leaving no drivers installed (which just makes Windows decide to install one and I'm back to 1080p). I also tried setting a Custom Resolution in the Intel Graphics Control Panel. This gives me an error: "The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity".

What else can I do to get 3440x1440 resolution in normal Windows?

**Relevant systems specs:**

- Windows 10 (21H1)
- Intel Core i5-3570K
- ASUS ASUS P8Z77-V LK (BIOS v 1402)
- Acer EI342CKR

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD 4000 (I have that on one machine here) does not support the high resolution you want.

[Intel HD 4000](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Intel-HD-4000-HDMI-2560x1440-resolution/m-p/375068)

> Intel graphics does not support dual-link, therefore 1920x1200 is the
> maximum for DVI and HDMI, 2560x1440 is only possible with a
> displayport port. This is stated in every specification sheet.

You may wish to ask ASUS support to see what they say.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. I was hoping since I was using displayport that I could get higher. Then how do I force Windows to use whatever default driver it uses in Safe Mode?

Comment: I went through several sites and the HD4000 will not do 3440x1440 in any reference I saw. Certainly not for my own Intel driver here.